# Traveling wave solving the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> A function $u(x,t)$ is called a traveling wave if it has the form $u(x,t) = f(x - at)$, for some function $f$, called the waveform, and some number $a$, called the wave speed.
>
> a.) Show that if a traveling wave solves the wave equation, and the waveform is not a line, then $a = \pm c$.
>
> b.) Show that for the diffusion equation, there are traveling wave solutions with any speed. What is the general form of the waveform for a given speed $a$?

I am not sure how to proceed with this, any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Attempted solution a.) A wave equation is of the form $$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0$$
Suppose the solution is of the form $u(x,t) = f(x - at)$. Then we have
$$u_{tt} = (a)^2 f^{\prime\prime}(x - at), \ \ u_{xx} = f^{\prime \prime}(x - at)$$
Thus from the wave equation we have $$(a)^2 f^{\prime\prime}(x - at) - c^2f^{\prime \prime}(x - at) = 0$$ Hence we must have $a = \pm c$ in order for this PDE to be satisfied.

Comment: For a) the point about the waveform not being a line just means that $f''(y) \neq 0$ for some $y$. Since the given $u$ satisfies the wave equation, just compute $u_{tt}, u_{xx}$ and see what you end up withe.

Comment: @copper.hat I made an edit to my post, am I sort of on the right track for part a.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wolfgang-1 , regards. I may give partial detail.

> For the 1st question :

- A wave equation is of the form : $$  u_{tt} - c^{2} u_{xx} = 0 $$
  You could check that $u(x,t) = f(x-at)$ solves the equation if $a^{2} = c^{2}$ and $f$ is not a line.

I am not familiar with your method. But the 1st question could be solved this way : 'presume' the solution is of the form $ u(x,t) = f(x-at) $, so that

$$  a^{2}f''(\xi) - c^{2}f''(\xi) = 0, \:\: \text{with} \: \xi = x -at  $$

from here you can see that the solution $f(x-at)$ must have $a = \pm c$. Note that $f$ must not be a line, if it is then it's 2nd derivative would be 0. This  answers the 1st question.

You could try to visualize $u(x,t)= \cos\left[k(x-ct)\right]+ \cos\left[k(x+ct)\right] $ (with small $k$, so that the wave directions is more visible)
$\\$
$\\$
$\\$

> For the 2nd :

- A 1D diffusion equation is of the form : 
  $$ u_{t} = K u_{xx}, \:\: K > 0  $$ If you put $u(x,t) = f(x - at)$, then from the PDE you could get

$$ f''(\xi) + \frac{a}{K}f'(\xi) = 0, \:\:\ \ \ \text{with   } \:\:  \xi = x- at  $$

So there are travelling-wave solutions for the PDE, which is achieved by solving this ODE. You can solve this ODE and get the waveform $f(\xi)$, which is a translation of exponential function

$$ u(x,t) = f(\xi) = e^{-\frac{a}{K}(x-at)}  $$

Hope this would help. Regards, Arief.

Comment: For the first question, should I use d'Alembert's formula. I am not famaliar with solving these types of questions.

Comment: I am not sure if I answered your first question if you could have a look at my edit

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 from your question, the part a.), is to show that if the travelling wave solution $f(x-at)$ is a solution to the wave equation, then $a= \pm c$. If $f(x-at)$ is a solution, it means $u(x,t)=f(x-at)$ fits the wave eqn. To answer the question, you only need to show that $a$ must satisfy $a= \pm c $. What you have done is trying to find the exact solution of the equation, and you have not try to 'presume' the solution is of the form $$u=f(x-at)$$ Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand the solution being $u(x,t) = f(x - ct) + h (c + ct)$ but I don't see how we are going to have the form $F(x - at)$ with $a = \pm c$

Comment: I need some more help if you can

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 I edited the answer for the 1st one. Related to my previous comment : The wave equation (the basic one we study to use here) is linear, so the superpositions of functions with form $F(x-at)$ (provided it is not a line) is also a solution, with the value $a$ must be either $c$ or either $-c$. Example : $$ u(x,t) = A\cos \left[ k(x-ct) \right]  $$  is a solution. This also :
$$ u(x,t) = B\cos \left[ k(x+ct) \right]  $$ But this one is not :
$$ u(x,t)= C \cos \left[ k(x+ (c+0.01)t) \right]  $$
Pertain to this topic, may I ask what subject you are currently studying? Thanks.

Comment: I have finished my masters in Financial Mathematics, and I am studying Partial Differential Equations 1 this summer just because I haven't take it formally before

Comment: With the first question when we presume $u(x,t) = f(x - at)$ I don't understand the next line "so that $$a^2f^{\prime\prime}(\xi) - c^2f^{\prime\prime}(\xi) = 0 \ \ \text{with} \ \ \xi  = x - at$$ Where does that come from?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 If $u=f(x-at)$ is a solution to the PDE, then this means it fits to be put to the PDE : 
$$  u_{tt} = (a)^{2} f''(x-at), \:\:\:\: u_{xx} = f''(x-at)  $$ 
Then put these two results to the wave equation PDE. From there you can see how $a$ must be $a= \pm c $, I use $\xi$ to nickname $x-at$ as a variable.

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you for your patience. I made an edit to my post with an attempted solution could you check to see if I am getting it right now?

Comment: Great, the hence I think was a point towards not fully understanding but yea I get it now thank you